# Schema reconciliation

Tags: schema, datastage, reconciliation

I have written a case statement as :

Case when currency=‘Abc’ then outstanding_bal else null end as outstanding _balances_RO

And i my job is failing saying this error messege

Source is ODBC connector , connected to Microsoft SQL server.

Schema reconciliation detected a type mismatch for field outstanding_balances_RO . When moving data from field type varchar(min=0,max=58) into Decimal (15,3)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using an expression in the SELECT statement, wrap that expression in a CAST to force it to DECIMAL(15,3) data type.